# Summarize Pandas DataFrame by Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame and each column is a binary indicator 1/0. It has 4 columns (and 6 rows). I would like to produce a DataFrame that groups rows that are similar and the last (5th) column shows the number of rows that fit that category. Please see the sample below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1,0],
         [0,1,1,0],
         [0,0,0,1],
         [0,0,0,1],
         [1,1,1,0],
         [1,1,1,1],
         [1,1,1,0]])

res = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1,0,2],
         [0,0,0,1,2],
         [1,1,1,0,2],
         [1,1,1,1,1]])
```

I need to create the "res" DataFrame from df.

Comment: can you please define what you mean by "similar"? do you mean equal to as these are binary values?

Comment: Yes. Equal sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `groupby` + `size`

```
df.groupby(list(df)).size().to_frame('size').reset_index()
Out[612]: 
   0  1  2  3  size
0  0  0  0  1     2
1  0  1  1  0     2
2  1  1  1  0     2
3  1  1  1  1     1
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it in my code. It seems like what I needed! Thanks.

Comment: @Research100 ok :-) happy coding, btw if this is what you need, can you consider accept it ?